# Vagrant machine disappears after reboot the host machine

Tags: netbeans, vagrant, virtualbox

Well, the title explain the issue very well. I install my vagrant machine through vagrant up from netbeans plugin. I configure it and use it propperly. Then i halt the machine, shut down my host machine, and when i start my host the vagrant machine has disappeared. No config files, no machine itself. Didn't find any documentation on this issue and i need the vagrant machine, so i install a new one every day so i can propperly debug my work project. I dont know what to do nor try, because I´ve only been using vagrant for a few weeks on a new job, but im wasting a lot of time on this daily instalation and i need to solve this. I appreciate any help.
Any ideas?

Vagrantfile:

```
    require 'yaml'

dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))

configValues = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config.yaml")
data         = configValues['vagrantfile-local']

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.6.0'

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box     = "#{data['vm']['box']}"
  config.vm.box_url = "#{data['vm']['box_url']}"

  if data['vm']['hostname'].to_s.strip.length != 0
    config.vm.hostname = "#{data['vm']['hostname']}"
  end

  if data['vm']['network']['private_network'].to_s != ''
    config.vm.network 'private_network', ip: "#{data['vm']['network']['private_network']}"
  end

  data['vm']['network']['forwarded_port'].each do |i, port|
    if port['guest'] != '' && port['host'] != ''
      config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: port['guest'].to_i, host: port['host'].to_i
    end
  end

  if !data['vm']['post_up_message'].nil?
    config.vm.post_up_message = "#{data['vm']['post_up_message']}"
  end

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostmanager')
    hosts = Array.new()

    if !configValues['apache']['install'].nil? &&
        configValues['apache']['install'].to_i == 1 &&
        configValues['apache']['vhosts'].is_a?(Hash)
      configValues['apache']['vhosts'].each do |i, vhost|
        hosts.push(vhost['servername'])

        if vhost['serveraliases'].is_a?(Array)
          vhost['serveraliases'].each do |vhost_alias|
            hosts.push(vhost_alias)
          end
        end
      end
    elsif !configValues['nginx']['install'].nil? &&
           configValues['nginx']['install'].to_i == 1 &&
           configValues['nginx']['vhosts'].is_a?(Hash)
      configValues['nginx']['vhosts'].each do |i, vhost|
        hosts.push(vhost['server_name'])

        if vhost['server_aliases'].is_a?(Array)
          vhost['server_aliases'].each do |x, vhost_alias|
            hosts.push(vhost_alias)
          end
        end
      end
    end

    if hosts.any?
      contents = File.open("#{dir}/puphpet/shell/ascii-art/hostmanager-notice.txt", 'r'){ |file| file.read }
      puts "\n\033[32m#{contents}\033[0m\n"

      if config.vm.hostname.to_s.strip.length == 0
        config.vm.hostname = 'puphpet-dev-machine'
      end

      config.hostmanager.enabled           = true
      config.hostmanager.manage_host       = true
      config.hostmanager.ignore_private_ip = false
      config.hostmanager.include_offline   = false
      config.hostmanager.aliases           = hosts
    end
  end

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-cachier')
    config.cache.scope = :box
  end

  data['vm']['synced_folder'].each do |i, folder|
    if folder['source'] != '' && folder['target'] != ''
      if folder['sync_type'] == 'nfs'
        config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{i}", type: 'nfs'
        config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
      elsif folder['sync_type'] == 'smb'
        config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{i}", type: 'smb'
      elsif folder['sync_type'] == 'rsync'
        rsync_args = !folder['rsync']['args'].nil? ? folder['rsync']['args'] : ['--verbose', '--archive', '-z']
        rsync_auto = !folder['rsync']['auto'].nil? ? folder['rsync']['auto'] : true
        rsync_exclude = !folder['rsync']['exclude'].nil? ? folder['rsync']['exclude'] : ['.vagrant/']

        config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{i}",
          rsync__args: rsync_args, rsync__exclude: rsync_exclude, rsync__auto: rsync_auto, type: 'rsync'
      else
        config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{i}",
          group: 'www-data', owner: 'www-data', mount_options: ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777']
      end
    end
  end

  config.vm.usable_port_range = (data['vm']['usable_port_range']['start'].to_i..data['vm']['usable_port_range']['stop'].to_i)

  if data['vm']['chosen_provider'].empty? || data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'virtualbox'
    ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'virtualbox'

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|
      data['vm']['provider']['virtualbox']['modifyvm'].each do |key, value|
        if key == 'memory'
          next
        end
        if key == 'cpus'
          next
        end

        if key == 'natdnshostresolver1'
          value = value ? 'on' : 'off'
        end

        virtualbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, "--#{key}", "#{value}"]
      end

      virtualbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--memory', "#{data['vm']['memory']}"]
      virtualbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cpus', "#{data['vm']['cpus']}"]

      if data['vm']['hostname'].to_s.strip.length != 0
        virtualbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--name', config.vm.hostname]
      end
    end
  end

  if data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'vmware_fusion' || data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'vmware_workstation'
    ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = (data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'vmware_fusion') ? 'vmware_fusion' : 'vmware_workstation'

    config.vm.provider 'vmware_fusion' do |v|
      data['vm']['provider']['vmware'].each do |key, value|
        if key == 'memsize'
          next
        end
        if key == 'cpus'
          next
        end

        v.vmx["#{key}"] = "#{value}"
      end

      v.vmx['memsize']  = "#{data['vm']['memory']}"
      v.vmx['numvcpus'] = "#{data['vm']['cpus']}"

      if data['vm']['hostname'].to_s.strip.length != 0
        v.vmx['displayName'] = config.vm.hostname
      end
    end
  end

  if data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'parallels'
    ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'parallels'

    config.vm.provider 'parallels' do |v|
      data['vm']['provider']['parallels'].each do |key, value|
        if key == 'memsize'
          next
        end
        if key == 'cpus'
          next
        end

        v.customize ['set', :id, "--#{key}", "#{value}"]
      end

      v.memory = "#{data['vm']['memory']}"
      v.cpus   = "#{data['vm']['cpus']}"

      if data['vm']['hostname'].to_s.strip.length != 0
        v.name = config.vm.hostname
      end
    end
  end

  ssh_username = !data['ssh']['username'].nil? ? data['ssh']['username'] : 'vagrant'

  config.vm.provision 'shell' do |s|
    s.path = 'puphpet/shell/initial-setup.sh'
    s.args = '/vagrant/puphpet'
  end
  config.vm.provision 'shell' do |kg|
    kg.path = 'puphpet/shell/ssh-keygen.sh'
    kg.args = "#{ssh_username}"
  end
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => 'puphpet/shell/install-ruby.sh'
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => 'puphpet/shell/install-puppet.sh'

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.facter = {
      'ssh_username'     => "#{ssh_username}",
      'provisioner_type' => ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'],
      'vm_target_key'    => 'vagrantfile-local',
    }
    puppet.manifests_path = "#{data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['manifests_path']}"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "#{data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['manifest_file']}"
    puppet.module_path    = "#{data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['module_path']}"

    if !data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['options'].empty?
      puppet.options = data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['options']
    end
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell do |s|
    s.path = 'puphpet/shell/execute-files.sh'
    s.args = ['exec-once', 'exec-always']
  end
  config.vm.provision :shell, run: 'always' do |s|
    s.path = 'puphpet/shell/execute-files.sh'
    s.args = ['startup-once', 'startup-always']
  end
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => 'puphpet/shell/important-notices.sh'

  if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa")
    config.ssh.private_key_path = [
      "#{dir}/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa",
      "#{dir}/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/insecure_private_key"
    ]
  end

  if !data['ssh']['host'].nil?
    config.ssh.host = "#{data['ssh']['host']}"
  end
  if !data['ssh']['port'].nil?
    config.ssh.port = "#{data['ssh']['port']}"
  end
  if !data['ssh']['username'].nil?
    config.ssh.username = "#{data['ssh']['username']}"
  end
  if !data['ssh']['guest_port'].nil?
    config.ssh.guest_port = data['ssh']['guest_port']
  end
  if !data['ssh']['shell'].nil?
    config.ssh.shell = "#{data['ssh']['shell']}"
  end
  if !data['ssh']['keep_alive'].nil?
    config.ssh.keep_alive = data['ssh']['keep_alive']
  end
  if !data['ssh']['forward_agent'].nil?
    config.ssh.forward_agent = data['ssh']['forward_agent']
  end
  if !data['ssh']['forward_x11'].nil?
    config.ssh.forward_x11 = data['ssh']['forward_x11']
  end
  if !data['vagrant']['host'].nil?
    config.vagrant.host = data['vagrant']['host'].gsub(':', '').intern
  end
end
```

As a provisional solution im saving from now on all the vm files into other folder so i can only restore and dont need to install again, but this is a lame solution and i wish to do this propperly.

Comment: Are you using linux system? If so, post your: ls ~/.vagrant.d/boxes  And also could be nice if you post your Vagrantfile

Comment: Im using a Windowd 7 host, and i updated my question with my Vagrantfile (this was set up by a former companion who's no longer workin here): 
Thank for the quick answer!

Comment: I recommend you to install the machine by yourself using the cmd.exe. After that open VirtualBox or the Provider you are using and check where is the VM located, that can help us to solve the issue :). And post this file content: data = configValues['vagrantfile-local'] vagrantfile-local

Comment: I tried to set up vagrant with cmd and with cygwin and i have the same problem. The file location of the vm is set propperly, but empty after reboot (both vm path and config files path)

Comment: its probably not that but can you check after vagrant halt that your machine is still there ? maybe someone made an alias to destroy when you run halt

Comment: I checked it and vagrant still there.

Comment: I booted today and the vagrant machine still there so it might be the netbeans vagrant up the non working well command, because the last time i set vagrant up was through cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

This question is of low quality and I'd recommend closing it if we can't fully describe what the issue that you were having and the solution to that issue.  Keep in mind, you're able to submit answers to your own question.  That way, other people who come across this issue will understand how you fixed the problem.  Typically, you can discover a lot by searching "debugging X" (e.g. Google -> "debugging vagrant").

Short of that, something that might be useful to you is looking at the machine console (GUI) while your VM is booting.  Since you're using Virtualbox, this is quite easy.  In the section of your Vagrantfile that begins with `config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|` , add the following :

```
virtualbox.gui = true
```

This is a common approach, described in the documentation: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html

Comment: thanks for the explanation. ill keep it in mind for the next questions.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this i just stop launching vagrant from netbeans and started using it from cygwin. This way it dont disappear. Still dont know why it removes the machine if i launch it from netbeans, but i need to use it at work so i have to do it this way and move on. Thanks everyone for the answers and the time spent.